# Where I find the info about what plants, trees can be planted in a locality

Tags: climate-change, climate, plant

I would like to know what plants, trees can be planted in a locality. I wanted this info around the globe based on latitude and longitude or by some other means. Is there a source organisation/source that maintains this data?

Comment: I think this is called plant hardiness zones. Here is one for India, however I can't attest that it is accurate, but it may help you. I think if you did a search you may be able to find a better graphic.https://www.mashrita.com/usda-hardiness-zones-context-india-major-cities/ You can of course search for hardiness zones in other countries too.

Comment: USDA= U.S. Department of Agriculture.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon! I will also search a little more if there is a consolidated place where we can find this data for all the countries on the planet.

Comment: @Gordon: Hardiness zones are useful but incomplete.  The amount & timing of precipitation is also an important factor.  For instance, many European & eastern US natives (lawn grass is perhaps the most familiar example) won't grow in much of the West unless irrigated, even though temperatures are similar.  Likewise many natives of the arid west don't do well in the humid east.  The "Sunset Western Gardening Book" has an expanded set of zones that takes this into account for the western US.  Perhaps asking on the Gardening site would get better answers?

Comment: @jamesqf  you did such a good job, I upvoted your comment.  I certainly have no objection to the question being transferred.